# More verbose logging in tezos-client

Tags: tezos-client, network, logging

I have some problems connecting to a node through `tezos-client`. Specifically I cannot succesfully run  `tezos-client -l -A rpcalpha.tzbeta.net -P 443 -S config update` to connect to a testnet node. It fails on a GET request to https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols (Neither of the two HTTP requests are sent as the TCP or SSL connection is never established).

```
>>>>0: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/version
>>>>1: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ETIMEDOUT, "connect", "")"
```

But when I run `curl -v https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols` I get a `200 OK` response. `curl -v https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/version` also works.

It would be easier for me to debug the problem, which is probably network related, if I could get verbose logs of what `tezos-client` is doing, specifically the HTTP requests' headers would be useful. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can add argument `-l --log-requests: log all requests to the node` to `tezos-client` to see the connection.

Although this won't show you the headers, you can see the `tezos-client -A rpcalpha.tzbeta.net ...` tries to connect to `http://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:8732`. To connect to `https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443` instead, you will want to add the following arguments:

- `-S --tls: use TLS to connect to node.`
- `-P --port <number>: RPC port of the node` with 443

To see the list of all available arguments, check out `tezos-client --help`.

Comment: The problem persists with these arguments, unfortunately
```
$ tezos-client -l -A rpcalpha.tzbeta.net -P 443 config update
>>>>0: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/version
>>>>1: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
Warning:
  Failed to acquire the protocol version from the node
  Rpc request failed:
     - meth: GET
     - uri: https://rpcalpha.tzbeta.net:443/chains/main/blocks/head/protocols
     - error: Unable to connect to the node: "Unix.Unix_error(Unix.ETIMEDOUT, "connect", "")"
```

Comment: it looks like you're missing the `-S` for TLS connection

Comment: I'm bad at copy/pasting. Sorry. It is there. To be specific: The command works on one network but not on another.

Comment: So: I am having networking issues and I am asking for the option of more logs from `tezos-client`. Is that an option you can add?

Comment: Question updated